# Timeseries from the CIA World Factbook

Tags: data-request

We're looking for some datasets (preferably time-series) on the percentage of people in different countries who adhere to different religions (like [here](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2122.html#sw)), speak different languages (like [here](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2098.html#sw)) or belong to different ethnic groups (like here - oops I can only post two links...).

I have heard that there are parsers for the [CIA World Factbook](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/) (WFB). But does anybody know whether those also work on 'old' versions of the WFB, and if so - how far back? So if we were to run them on older versions of WFB on [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) - would they work? Or better yet: is there anybody who's already done that?

I'd be very grateful for any hints.

-Stephan

Comment: Commenting so I can follow this because I've wanted WFB data in something other than a PDF.

Answer (score 2):

### Religion

If you are happy with a single value per country, the world bank got you covered with the dataset [World Development Report 2011](http://data.worldbank.org/data-catalog/wdr2011). It contains time series from 1960 to 2009 for all countries of high-level indicators, summarising statistics from various public sources. Among them is the CIA World Factbook.

The accompanying [codebook](http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/WDR2011%20CodeBook.pdf) on the field `DominantReligion_EB_CIA`:

> If **50% or more  of the population adhere to a particular religion**, 
>   that country is deemed to contain a dominant religion. The various 
>   denominations of a particular religion are added together. The 
>   coding is as follows: 0= No dominant religion; 1= Christianity; 2= Islam; 3= Buddhism; 4= Hinduism; 5= Judaism; 6= Shintoism.

There are other fields related to religion in that dataset as well, like `Freedom_religion_CIRI` (indicator to freedom of practising one's religion), `Relipol_Montalvo_Querol` (religious polarization score), `Relifra_Montalvo_Querol` (religious fractionalization).

### Language

Here the dataset only has one numeric field `OfficialLanguages_EB_CIA`, measuring the number of official language per country, and four boolean columns indicating whether English, French, Spanish, Arabic are among these official languages.